# asynchronous client server WCF

Tags: wcf, asynchronous, client

my client run a service like that:

```
ServiceHost=new ServiceHost(typeof(Service2),new Uri("http://..."));
ServiceMetadataBehavior smb=new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
smb.HttpGetEnabled=true;
smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion=PolicyVersion.Policy15;
sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
sh.open();
```

in the Service2 class (that implement Iservice) i added a function:

```
bool returnResult(bool res)
{
return res;
}
```

my client send a request to the server to validate XML file, and the server return true/false by activating the returnResult function through the server2 that run on the client.
how can the result can get to the client?
p.s i know there somthing with event but i don't know how...

Comment: I read question three times and I don't understand it.

Comment: i send a message to the client, and the client suppose to answer me through a server that run on the client...

Comment: What don't you use a standard async pattern (Begin/End) in your WCF service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it! i declared a static event in a different class. the client add a function tho this event. the server call the server on the client with the result, and the client's server make the Invokatin of the event with this value.